# Magento: Currency change won't affect frontend

Tags: php, magento, currency

I've recently managed to migrate/make a copy of my website to a new hosting.

Now I want to change the currency of the site, I go the typical Admin > Config > General --> Currency Options: Deslelect all other currencies that I don't need, and Change the **Display Currency** to what it have to, but still fails to show up the proper currency...

I reindexed, cleaned chache with no luck, anyone know how to force this? In case there is no other way?

Thanks in advance! :D

Cheers.

**Update 07/02/20023:**
I changed the following xml's in order to try cahnge the Locale options and adding the missing symbol for Peruan Nuevo Sol:
    en.xml
    en_US.xml
    es.xml
    es_ES.xml
    config.xml (the one on `lib/Zend/Data..`)

The funny part is that in the Magento's Backend, it shows de correct currency (S/.) butI don't know why it wont show on the frontend... I cleaned all possible caches, even the session folders, but it still doesn't change from EURO...

Any clue?

Comment: Didi you changed the display settings?

Comment: Yes as I stated in the question, I changed **Base Currency** and **Default Display Currency** to the new currency, and even disabled the old currency, leaving only the new one.

Comment: think that you simply need to change the xml file with the locale settings

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which xml are you refering to?

Comment: I changed the es.xml to add the Peruan symbol, cause it was missing, cleaned all caches, even deleting the var/cache content without much luck..

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I found that the issues were:

1) I hadn't set up exchange rates for the newly added currencies (so there was no way the system could have calculated the prices in the new rates). Solution: System -> Manage Currency -> Rates -> Import then Save.

2) My own browser was cookied to use a specific currency, because I'd used the currency-changer on the website (in the front-end, i.e. the end-user's view). Solution: currency chooser, or delete cookies.